# Fullcalendar dropping events on top (dayGrid view)

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

When dropping events on another day, I want them to drop at the very top. I have searched docs, StackO, issues on git, feature requests, and can't seem to find what I am looking for.

Wondering if anyone has had a similar issue, that can chime in with their solution.

Here's what's currently happening on my end: https://www.loom.com/share/1f8728a80e6f4962855ec24216256e61

It seems events are ordered by some timestamp?

Yes, I am using `eventOrder`, but it only fires up correctly if I re-render the calendar.

Would love it to work on `eventDrop` — simply be dropped at the top.

**EDIT:**
Here's my current code —

```
function loadThisCalendar(allTasks, renderDate) {

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

        plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'interaction' ],
        defaultView: 'dayGridWeek',
        defaultDate: renderDate,

        // this works fine on refresh
        // wish it worked like this on drop as well
        eventOrder: '-task_update_date',

        firstDay: 1,
        editable: true,
        eventDurationEditable: false,

        // Events
        events: allTasks,

        // Changing date of the event               
        eventDrop: function(info) {

           // Drop success

        } 

    });

}
```

Comment: can you share some code, Minimal Viable Code to check errors if any?

Comment: sorry and thanks @Dharmang / added my current code up on the original answer // Again, refreshing calendar works fine, but I wish I can control the drop to be always on top, before refresh or any other calls I make // Because I can do work around, but wish there was a clean native way, if there is one?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't one. Perhaps you should make a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features)

Comment: Do you know @ADyson how do they currently order on drop... it seems haphazard for now? Some internal timestamp... can't really make it out?

Comment: No, I don't know. You'd have to check the source code.